# Log clients real IP in Apache from haproxy

Tags: apache-2.4, haproxy

I have setup a pair of new haproxy (v1.5) load balancers, and put 2 webservers (apache on Centos 6) behind it. I've setup X-forwarded-for and I can see the clients real IP in the access_log on the webservers.

However, I don't see the clients real IP's in the error_log, there it only logs the haproxy nodes IP's. What am I doing wrong? Attached is the log config for the webserver.

```
    LogLevel warn

    <IfModule log_config_module>

    LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common        

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O         
     LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined

    </IfModule>

    SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/check\.txt$" dontlog
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined env=!dontlog
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't shown it to us, I guess you're using the default [ErrorLogFormat](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errorlogformat) which doesn't contain the information you want. You will have to use the ErrorLogFormat directive to configure what is logged.

Answer (score 1):

As of Apache 2.4 the [`ErrorLogFormat`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errorlogformat) directive is available which allows you tune what gets logged in the ErrorLog.

Most reverse proxies add a header with the original IP-address of the client, which you can log in addition to or instead of the IP-address of your reverse proxy.

A fairly common header that (reverse) proxies set is `X-Forwarded-For: <client-ip>` which you would capture with `%{VARNAME}i`  :

```
%{X-Forwarded-For}i
```

And for instance

```
ErrorLogFormat "[%t] [%l] [pid %P] %F: %E: [client: %{X-Forwarded-For}i forwarded by: %a] %M"
```